# Размер колонки table css

Tags: html, css

у меня есть таблица, в которой есть несколько колонок. В каждую ячейку  записываются данные в каком то теге, например `<td><div>текст</div></td>`
Я ставлю колонке размер 30% и всё работает отлично, до того момента, пока текст в колонке не  станет очень длинным.
То есть если в ячейку написать `<td><div>ааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааа</div></td>`, то даже при наличии overflow:hidden, весь этот текст будет отображен в одной строке и таблица съедет. Можно ли как то это исправить и скрыть текст, который не должен влезать?

Answer (score 0):

Может это вам поможет

```css
table {
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 100%;
}

td {
  width: 30%;
  overflow: hidden;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div>123</div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div>12asdasdas12asdasdasdasdasdasdasdas3dasdasdasd12aadasdasdasdasdsdasdasdasda12asdasdasdasdasdasdasdas3sdasdasdas3asdas3</div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div>123</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```